# Scala regular expression with $ (end of string)

Tags: regex, scala

I'm somewhat in difficulty. (I'm pro in regexps but not much used them in scala/java).
I have numeric string of 11 chars in length, need just last 10, so:

```
val Pattern = """(\d{10})$""".r
"79283767219" match {
  case Pattern(m) => m
}
```

It gives `MatchError`, but why?! What have I misunderstood?

Comment: I mean, why does it try to match the whole string? It has no bounding to the start of the line

Comment: Ok, I had understanding of **what's going on** just from start, I'm interested in how to make it work properly, not to match like if there are implicit ^ and $.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you have 11 digits, not 10. You can set "10 and more" with `{10,}`. To match only end of the string you need to explicitly specify full pattern:

```
 val Pattern = """.*(\d{10})$""".r
```

**Update:** until you're on Scala 2.10 and you can use Daniel's `unanchored` you can workaround it like so:

```
Pattern.findFirstIn("79283767219")
```

Comment: May you give a link where it specified - explicitly? Regex understands `^` and `$` symbols, but somehow it behaves as if they were there implicitly. Is this unavoidable or maybe there is some kind of modifiers or options?

Comment: @dmitry just use `Pattern.findFirstIn("79283767219")`.

Comment: Seems in my case this is the solution. Add in answer, ok?

Comment: @dmitry It's specified on the scaladoc for `unapplySeq`.

Comment: Note that even with `unanchored` or `findFirstIn`, the `^` character still means start of whole string, not start of a line. So, you need something like `(^|\n)` to get the start of a line (i.e. start of string or just a newline).

Answer (score 12):

When you match against a regex pattern, the regex pattern should match *the whole* string. That is, it's like the regex pattern started with `^` and ended with `$`. The reason behind this is that a `match` is supposed to deconstruct the whole of the left side on the right side.

With Scala 2.10, you can call `unanchored` to get a matcher that will do partial matches, like this:

```
val Pattern = """(\d{10})$""".r.unanchored
```

Be assured that *your* anchor will be preserved. It's just the expectation that the match should apply over the whole string that will be dropped.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! I didn't know about `unanchored`. I presume it adds `.*` at *both* ends of the pattern? That would not work for the original question, I don't think. It also might interact badly with the `$` that's already there. In some RE dialects (too lazy to check now) `$` only is a right-side anchor when it's the last character in the RE. How smart is `unanchored`?

Comment: @randall-shulz I checked it in 2.10. It works as intended. Explicit anchors work like I think they should have behaved from start.

Comment: That's fine, but I think it's best to use them the way they're designed, as a full match. Neither way is inherently better than the other. If it were a search, you'd have to explicitly anchor it. As a match, you have to explicitly float it. Personally, I like it the way it is. I rarely want search when I use a `RegEx` in a Scala `match` construct.

Comment: @RandallSchulz Unanchored changes the method called when doing unapplySeq, without doing any change to the pattern itself. It can have serious performance gains depending on the pattern.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: Un-anchoring the pattern could only make the process of matching take longer, as  far as I can see.

Comment: @RandallSchulz That's only true if you do not have to prepend `.*` to your patterns just to satisfy the anchoring. If you do, then you are subject to exponential backtracking on most regex implementations, including Java's.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: I realize `unanchored` is not the same as tacking on `.*` at either end, but since there are many more ways for a floating _search_ to potentially match any given scrutinee, it will always be more expensive than an anchored _match_.

Comment: @RandallSchulz That's not what I meant. Let's say you have a pattern like `"\s*def".r`, and you want to match on that, so you rewrite it as `".*\s*def.*".r`. That pattern is subject to exponential backtracking, while `"\s*def".r.unanchored` is not.

Comment: Note that even with `unanchored` or `findFirstIn`, the `^` character still means start of whole string, not start of a line. So, you need something like `(^|\n)` to get the start of a line (i.e. start of string or just a newline).

Answer (score 3):

Be aware, when a `RegEx` instance such as `Pattern` in your example is used in a `match` construct, it is *not* a search, it's a *match!* Meaning that it must match the entire value being matched (called, in Scala parlance, the "scrutinee"—`79283767219` in your example).

*That* explains why your example got a `MatchError`.

Comment: Ok, so, is there some way to avoid this? Without rewriting regexp. Maybe without pattern matching.

Comment: Without altering the regular expression? No. Float the pattern with `.*` as necessary.